# Mahindra Scorpio ECU problem

Tags: electronic-control-module

I am facing problem while displaying metrics on my Android phone, i have this [Bluetooth Module](http://www.ebay.in/itm/112459633441?aff_source=Sok-Goog) and using torque (Lite) app from Play Store. Device is connecting to the phone quickly, but it's taking much time to connect with the ECU. I have to disconnect and reconnect Module many times to get connected with the ECU properly.

But even after connecting, The module is sending incorrect values, Speedo meter and RPM are going mad.

But the same Module is working perfectly with my Hyundai Verna, Connecting fast, and giving correct numbers.

what could be the problem.?

Comment: Are you able to select your Scorpio, crde, and diesel under torque?

Comment: Where is that option?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "Torque" is pretty much a free app, and that Hyundai vehicles are sold worldwide, and use a relatively popular OBD II protocol.

I'm guessing a Mahindra Scorpio is using a less common communication protocol that isn't fully supported by Torque.

It doesn't work with my 1997 Subaru either, so don't feel bad.

The Tenugi gets translated into Punjabi and then to Hindi and then to English. That takes a long long time...